# How to make camera have same rotation as an object but with an offset (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, offset, quaternions

So i have a car and a camera and so far here is the camera script:

```
 public GameObject car;
    public Vector3 offset;

    void Start()
    {
        offset = transform.position - car.transform.position;
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, car.transform.position + offset, 0.8f);
    }
}
```

This makes the camera smoothly move with the car, but now i want the camera to also have the same rotation as the car but with the starting offset.

Comment: I suggest you to use **Cinemachine** for this.
You can make a very comfortable setting with *VirtualCamera*.
Smooth transitions, distance tracking, rotation tracking etc.
Everything is pretty easy.
https://unity.com/unity/features/editor/art-and-design/cinemachine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just the "same" way store the original delta rotation like

```
Quaternion offsetRotation;

private void Start ()
{
    offset = transform.position - car.transform.position;

    offsetRotation = transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(car.transform.rotation);
}
```

And then later

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, car.transform.position + offset, 0.8f);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, car.transform.rotation * offsetRotation, 0.8f);
}
```